# Property 'name' does not exist on type 'MyComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to angular2 dont know a thing about 1, please tell why its showing me this error and how do I resolve this.

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component
({

  selector: 'my-component',

  template: `<div>Hello my name is {{name}}. <button (click)="sayMyName()">Say my name</button></div>`
})


export class MyComponent

 {
  constructor() {
   this.name = 'Max'
  }

  sayMyName() 
{

    console.log('My name is',this.name)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a property before you're referring to it

```
export class MyComponent {
  name:string; // <<<===
  constructor() {
   this.name = 'Max'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your property first

```
export class MyComponent {
    name: string;

    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Max'
    }

    sayMyName() {
        console.log('My name is',this.name)
    }
}
```